# Why does my skrollr parallax effect not work properly when the height of my window gets longer?

Tags: parallax, skrollr

I got my parallax effect to work perfectly on my laptop screen size. As soon as I viewed my site on a larger screen I noticed the parallax effect was not finishing because there was not enough room to scroll down. How do I fix this issue? Below is a snippet of my code showing two of the elements moving as I scroll down. I am using data attributes to transform. Should I be using something else? You can view my site here http://nsohail.github.io/Project3-HTML/

```
<div id="slide-1" class="slide" 
                        data-0="transform:translate(-770px,0px);"
                        data-10p="transform:translate(-770px,0px);"
                        data-100p="transform:translate(185px,0px);">
</div>

<div id="slide-1" class="slide" 
                        data-0="transform:translate(770px,0px);"
                        data-10p="transform:translate(770px,0px);"
                        data-100p="transform:translate(-220px,0px);">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 100p (percentages) use pixels so it will end at an exact spot no matter what the screen height is. So adjust your percentages to just numbers. For example data-0, data-10, data-100.